# How to create an expandable column in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I hope I can explain this well enough so that you can understand the problem.  I've created a Crystal Report with 2 columns of fields.  The right column contains on large field containing a description, the left column contains a series of small fields like so:

Marketing           {description}
{marketing}
Sales Points
{sales points}
Also Available
{also available}

The marketing, sales points, also available sections will not display for all products and can be of different sizes, so I placed the fields into different sections in a subreport.  This works fine for a single record in the dataset, but when I have multiple records the subreport shows all data on every page.

My question is, can I set up the subreport so that it only displays the data from the record for the current page.  If not, is there a way I can have the marketing, sales, available sections expand and contract to fit any size of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out shortly after I posted.  I hadn't setup any linking between my subreport and the main report, this is why the subreport showed everything. I right-clicked the subreport and selected "Change subreport links" and then setup a link with the primary key.